# How do I fix missing required library in SplashActivity?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm fixing errors for an Android app that I didn't make and I'm not able to load it in the emulator. It says that I'm missing a required library:

```
 slf4j-1.6.1-jul.jar/slf4j-1.6.1-jul.jar/slf4j-1.6.1-jul.jar
```

How do I add this library or can I just delete it and it will work fine? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Download the file](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.6.1/jul-to-slf4j-1.6.1.jar)
put in the libs folder inside android project and add it in your project's build path.

Answer (score 1):

Download it from [here](http://www.slf4j.org/) and either put the `.jar` file in your project's lib folder, or add it to the build-path.

Comment: Which one do I download? I'm fairly new to Android. Thanks!

Comment: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.6.1/jul-to-slf4j-1.6.1.jar